# SQL - waiting for a rollback to complete

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, transactions, sqlexception

I am deleting a large amount of records using a `CommittableTransaction` with a 300 seconds timeout. Occasionally I am getting an error

> SqlException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

It seems after the timeout, SQL is performing rollback automatically and the rollback takes ~200 seconds to finish.

But my current C# code, catches the `SqlException` and checks the `TransactionStatus` (which is `Aborted`) and proceeds further. Since the rollback is in progress, I am supposed to wait until the rollback is completed. Is there a way to find the rollback status? Or how do I handle this situation?

Comment: you can set the timeout manually also..

Comment: Please note that Rollback is not initiated by C# code. It seems SQL server is performing rollback automatically after the transaction timeout.

Comment: @WPFLearner, There is no such thing as query timeout in SQL Server- it's purely client-side concept. Basically, after sending each statement to SQL Server the data provider layer waits for specified period of time and, if it is expired, sends low-level `Abort` command into the connection. So it's not your code that cancels the processing, yes, but it's a client-side code nevertheless.

Comment: @RogerWolf, I understand your point. On the client-side, Is there way to wait for the rollback to end?

Answer (score 0):

From here
[Implementing an Explicit Transaction using CommittableTransaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172146(v=vs.85).aspx)

> A CommittableTransaction object can be used across function calls and
>   threads. However, it is up to the application developer to handle
>   exceptions and specifically call the Rollback method in case of
>   failures.

I think you can explicit call [Transaction.Rollback(Exception)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms149788(v=vs.110).aspx) in the catching block the SqlException. So you wait for finished the operation rollback.

Comment: Tried Transaction.Rollback(Exception) in the SqlException handler, but it is not waiting for the rollback to end. Before calling Rollback, checked the Transaction status in the exception handler, it is already Aborted.